# How to restrict messages from notification HUB to authenticated users?

Tags: azure, security, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I heard that in order to restrict push notifications (from notification HUB) so that only authenticated users will receive messages, I have to check in the "Only Authenticated Users" checkbox. But I am not able to find it, I can see only "AUTHENTICATION REQUIRED" but that option is only if I need to add custom tags, in order to filter who is getting the message.

[image]

Could someone please direct me to a tutorial or something?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this. This explains how to setup.

https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter5/concepts/